# Power series representation of xln(3x+5)

Tags: calculus, power-series

I get to the point $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n3^{n+1}x^{n+2}}{(n+1)5^{n+1}}$ by using the geometric series and integrating etc. But I looked up the answer and it is what I have plus the term xln(5), where does this come from?

Comment: Can you provide more details to the question

Comment: That is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have written is the traditional power series for $x\ln( (3/5)x + 1)$, plugging in $y = 3/5x$ into the formula $\ln(1+y) = y - y^2/2 + y^3/3 + \cdots$.  In your case, you need to add an additional $x\ln(5)$ term to get $x\ln(5)+ x\ln( (3/5)x + 1) = x\ln(3x+5)$.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to know is :
$$ \ln(1+ax)=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

which comes from (by integeration) :
$$\frac{1}{1-ax}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} (-ax)^n$$

and of course $|ax|<1$